# how to read a hash password that is stored in a file?

Tags: go, security

Hello I created a program to practice which generates a password and stores it in a file and a function allows me to read it afterwards. To avoid storing the password in clear text, I wanted to store it in the file after hashing it but I cannot find a way to restore the password to its form before hashing to read it afterwards. Is there a way to reverse hash or another way to store passwords securely?

I tried to reverse the hash but without success, otherwise I wanted to encrypt the password with salting but the problem is that you have to store the salting key and therefore the security is lower.

Comment: "*... but I cannot find a way to restore the password to its form before hashing to read it afterwards. ...*" - And you shouldn't be able to. That is exactly what a cryptographic hash function does. According to the [corresponding `en.wikipedia.org` article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), one of the defining features is: "*finding an input string that matches a given hash value (a pre-image) is unfeasible, assuming all input strings are equally likely.*"

Answer (score 1):

You don't reverse the hash. Hashes can't be reversed: that's the whole point.

You store the salt and the hash in your database. When you want to validate a password you retrieve the salt and run the same hashing algorithm on the salt and password as you did to create the original hash.

If the result matches the original has you have a valid password.

An attacker reading hashes from your database cannot reverse engineer the process to arrive at the original password, so the method is secure.

Comment: Okay thanks for the response. the goal of my app was precisely to create a password manager like we find with Google but in a very simple way I generate plus I store a file, then final step I read the password to re-etulize it. I understand that there are ways to store data securely. I'm going to look into this voice.

Comment: @hecko You should reply explain that in your question so that potential answerers understand what problem you're trying to solve. Right now it reads as though you don't understand the hashing process, hence my answer. What you need is encryption, not hashing, but the weakness you then have is separating the encryption and decryption keys from the password data. I don't know how Google does it, but with their infrastructure it would be possible to spread the keys across many servers.

Comment: @Hecko If you want to implement a password manager, I recommend looking how existing password managers, e.g. [KeepassXC (`github.com`)](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc), solved the problem. The general approach is to use an encryption mechanism to encrypt the whole password safe, and decrypt it when needed. The passwords are stored in cleartext within the safe (which itself is encrypted).